# source code for "extract.samples()" from rethinking package?

Tags: r

I am trying to look at the source code for function `extract.samples()` from `rethinking` package on github with no success.

The best I could find is [**HERE**](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/blob/master/R/map2stan-class.r), but I'm wondering if that is the actual source code or not?

Comment: I'm confused why you think that wouldn't be the actual source code? anyway you can just run print(extract.samples) within R and compare

Comment: Are you confused because there are two methods called `extract.samples`?

Comment: You can see what is really going on by following the clues.  We know we are trying to find a function called `extract` from the `rstan` package. Here is a [start](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/3fba2157c619943ea806d835c6ba3f5290e7df71/rstan/rstan/R/stanfit-class.R#L419).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean what types of arguments are passed or how to call it? Like [this](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/blob/1def057174071beb212532d545bc2d8c559760a2/book_code_boxes.txt#L363)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  It is probably best that you thoroughly read the linked post. It is one of my favorite post on SO.  I have read the question and answers there several times and I learn something new every time. Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, thanks for your help. There are two other functions that I can't see the source code for, using `print(function.name)` method. First one is `link` and second one is `sim` any ideas?

Comment: again, read the assigned duplicate thoroughly. get anywhere should help.